# How Do I Use Case When with Group By statement

Tags: sql, group-by, cube

I have made a query but it don't give me what i want :

```
SELECT     Designation_projet, COUNT(*) AS [Nb Demande], CASE WHEN Validation = 0 THEN COUNT(*) END AS Validée, CASE WHEN Validation = 1 THEN COUNT(*) 
        END AS NonValidée, CASE WHEN Commandé = 0 THEN COUNT(*) END AS NonCommandé, 
       CASE WHEN Commandé <> 0 THEN COUNT(*) END AS Commandé,  SUM(TotalHT) AS TotalHT
FROM         V_DemandeAchat
GROUP BY Designation_projet,Commandé,Validation
```

Please help me to achieve my gool.
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using condition aggregation.  That means that the `CASE` expression is the argument to `SUM()` -- it goes "inside" not "outside":

```
SELECT Designation_projet, COUNT(*) AS [Nb Demande],
       SUM(CASE WHEN Validation = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Validée,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Validation = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NonValidée, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Commandé = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NonCommandé, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Commandé <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END AS Commandé,
       SUM(TotalHT) AS TotalHT
FROM V_DemandeAchat
GROUP BY Designation_projet;
```

If you want one row per `Designation_projet`, then that should be the only key in the `GROUP BY`.

Assuming `Validation` takes on only two values, you can simplify the first two aggregation expressions:

```
SELECT Designation_projet, COUNT(*) AS [Nb Demande],
       SUM(1 - Validation) as Validée,
       SUM(Validation = 1) as NonValidée, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Commandé = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NonCommandé, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Commandé <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END AS Commandé,
       SUM(TotalHT) AS TotalHT
FROM V_DemandeAchat
GROUP BY Designation_projet;
```

You may be able to simplify the `Commandé` expressions as well.

Comment: Thanks that's what i want

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT     Designation_projet, COUNT(*) AS [Nb Demande],sum(CASE WHEN Validation = 1 THEN 1 else 0 END AS Validée,sum( CASE WHEN Validation = 1 THEN 1 else 0
        END AS NonValidée, sum(CASE WHEN NonCommandé <> 1 THEN 1 else 0 END AS NonCommandé, 
       sum(CASE WHEN Commandé <> 1 THEN 1 else 0 END AS Commandé,  SUM(TotalHT) AS TotalHT
FROM         V_DemandeAchat
GROUP BY Designation_projet
```

Comment: I need just group by Designation_projet to have 2 lines in this case, you query give 4 lines